# Aligning a header?

Tags: html, css

I appologize if this question has already been posted. I looked for hours and couln't find it. I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS so I also appologize for my awful code.

I'm trying to align a H3 header directly under an H1 heading.

My code is:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">
    <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
    <h3 class="motto"><em>"Website motto"</em></h3>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.header{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: pink;
    color: deeppink;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Candara;
    background-image:;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    border-radius: 1%;
}

.moto{
}

.flag{
    height: 95px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1{
    line-height: 9%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 3%; 
}

.header h3{
    padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">
    <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
    <h3 class="motto"><em>"Website motto"</em></h3>
</div>
```

The H3 is significantly lower than everything else, and i would like it to be vertically centered with the flag.

Edit: Here's a mockup thing. I only use H3 as a style choice because I'm not really sure what else to do.

[What it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH2dT.png)

[How I'd like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PRC0.png)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Just as a separate point to your issue, for accessibility purposes your `h3` should really be a `h2` - please don't use heading tags for style purposes.

Comment: Not sure about what you're aiming for. Can you show us a mock up or explain a bit more where each element should be positionned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header{
 font-size: 15px;
 background-color: pink;
 color: deeppink;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: Candara;
 background-image:;
 padding-bottom: 0.5%;
 border-radius: 1%;
  display: flex;
}

.flag{
 height: 95px;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 12px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header h1{
 margin: 0;
}

.header h2 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">  
  <div class="content">  
  <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
  <h2 class="motto"><em>"Website motto"</em></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: pink;
    color: deeppink;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Candara;
    background-image:;
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    border-radius: 1%;
  display:flex;
}

.moto{
}

.flag{
    height: 95px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1{
    width:100%
    padding-left: 3%;   
}

.header p{
    padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">
    <div>
      <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
      <h3 class="motto"><em>"Website motto"</em></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

You just need to wrap both your h1 and h3 tags into another div.

Use the flex layout then.

Here is an example.

```
`https://codepen.io/Utsav91/pen/GzaBox`
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
.header {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: deeppink;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Candara;
  background-image: ;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}

.moto {
}

.flag {
  height: 95px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1 {
  line-height: 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.header p {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">
  <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
  <h3 class="motto"><em style="padding-left:4%;">"Website motto"</em></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: That just moved it a little more over. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your header elements and apply appropriate styling.

```css
.header {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: deeppink;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Candara;
  background-image: ;
  padding-bottom: 0.5%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}
.flag {
  height: 95px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header .header-text {
  line-height: 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 3%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.header p {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img class="flag" src="./images/MINFLAG.png">
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>Placeholder txt</h1>
    <h3 class="motto"><em>"Website motto"</em></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did few changes but you might need to customize.

```css
.header {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: deeppink;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Candara;
  background-image: ;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  border-radius: 1%;
}

.flag {
  height: 95px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}

.header p {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
      <img class="flag" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1280px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png">
      <h1 align="center">Placeholder txt</h1>
      <h3 align="center"><em>"Website motto"</em></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make it an h2 to follow semantic order of headers but you can style the h2 as an h3 if that is really what you want.

Comment: We normally give suggestions in Comments,

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here and didn't know.

Comment: Welcome @Jacob, to SO,  we are always new to something.. you can take over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help)